# Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

I saw this error when I was scraping dashboard with Capybara + Poltergeist. I already tried the option suggested in the other posts but didn't work yet.

```
Firing a click at co-ordinates [1571.5, 584] failed. Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector 'html body div#app div.layout div div.dashboard div.dashboard-content div.monitor div.fixed.loading.show' at this position. It may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click').
```

Options I tried

- Adding window_size got the same error. The coordinate(1571.5, 584) seems to be within the window size specified in the option(1600, 1200)

```
 Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
   Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, window_size: [1600, 1200])
 end
```

- Use `trigger("click")` instead of `.click`. This doesn't throw error but couldn't get the correct html response.

Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: use `save_and_open_screenshot` to see what exactly is showing on the page and what is overlapping.  Poltergeist/PhantomJS is pretty obsolete nowadays due to lack of support for modern CSS/JS so it's possible it's not actually rendering the page the way you think it is.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the screenshot, and the place where I tried to click was actually within the window.

Comment: I'm unclear whether that means you found the problem or that the screenshot didn't show another element overlapping it?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot didn't show any overlap for me but have been seeing the same error. I am trying to click the dropdown arrow to show a list, and the dropdown arrow sits on the right side of the screenshot.

Comment: The error message is giving you the selector of the element that Poltergeist thinks is overlapping  - html body div#app div.layout div div.dashboard div.dashboard-content div.monitor div.fixed.loading.show - and judging from the class name `fixed` I'm guessing it is a fixed position element on the right edge of the window (due to the click location shown) that is actually overlapping the element you're trying to click even though you think it isn't.  Take a look at the position of that element and verify.  You may need to use `execute_script` to scroll the wanted element more into the page.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still struggling to verify if the click location is overlapped, but what will be the solution for that if that's the issue?

Comment: As mentioned you can use `execute_script` to scroll the element out from under the fixed element.  Other options would be to change the window size so the element isn't overlapped, and/or swap from Poltergeist to another driver like Apparition or Selenium that render correctly with modern JS/CSS (and allow you to display the window for debugging purposes if desired)